# Why did the war end?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

This occurred while playing the Game of Thrones mod for Crusader Kings II and I'm not sure if this is a feature of the mod or the game itself.

I was playing as the Starks, things were going normally.  About a year into it, suddenly every title not in my kingdom joins Joffery and declares on me.  Crap hits the fan I lose much of the Riverlands.  I decided to plot to kill Joffery and succeeded.  Shortly after killing Joffery, my warscore was in the -90s and then I randomly surrendered.  I was imprisoned, lost all my titles and that was pretty much game over.

I can't figure why I just surrendered all of a sudden.  Was this due to a CK2 mechanic or something random in the mod?

Comment: Your warscore probably dropped to -100%. At that point the enemy can force you to surrender. It's not random. and it works the other way as well. If you get the warscore to 100% you can force the enemy to surrender as well.

Comment: Your warscore continually drops if the enemy holds the land(s) contested over in the war. I dont know how this applies in that mod, but I would assume you are contesting for 'the North' as a whole in independance war? In which case if much of the north is held by the enemy, your score will continually decrease regardless of war events

Comment: Both your comments combined answer my question.  The mod starts the North with a lot of territory and I was intentionally giving up a lot of the southern territory so I could go offensive.  Despite imprisoning the entire Lannister family the territory loss killed my war score.